# Symfony: stop propagation in exception event listener

Tags: symfony, exception

inside an exception event listener I have a code that in some situations can lead to a new exception. I tryed using a `try..catch` block but a new exception is been thrown.

```
    $is_admin = false;
    $event->stopPropagation();
    try
    {
        $is_admin = ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    }
    catch (Exception $e){}
```

I would like this exception to be silented by `catch`. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: You should be catching `\Exception` as `catch(Exception $e)` would be trying to catch the `Exception` in the same directory as you event listener. Also, `$is_admin = ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'));` would just return a boolean rather than create an exception.